# Sequelize Raw Query returns Array of TextRows

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I am using sequelize in my project. I am using the following format to get the results. But each row in the result is returned as textRow. Is it ok if I can directly access using the index or Do I need to convert textrow?
Need your suggestions.

```
const testQuery = await sequelizeConn.query(`select * from users where user_name = '${reqParams.userName}'`, {
         raw: true
      })
if(testQuery && testQuery.length > 0 && testQuery[0].length > 0){
}
```

Comment: Hi Team, Need some help here. Pls suggest

Comment: Hello! I'd like to understand, what resut would you like to get. I only can get that you don't like textrows for now

Comment: am ok with text rows. Is it advisable to access text rows like normal objects?

Comment: Yeah textrows are completely normal objects

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove raw:true because already it's working like raw query and try promise instead of async/await.

```js
    
         sequelize.query(`select * from users where user_name = ${reqParams.userName}`, {model: users})
          .then(function(result) {
         
            if(result && result.length > 0 && result[0].length > 0){
    console.log(result);
    }
            
          }).catch(error=>{
                  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Any specific reason to change to promises?

Comment: No , it's not compulsory you can also try with async/await i am just asking for debuging.